# Big Table in latex

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

Could you please helping me to draw a  nice big tables

like this one , I don't know how to mange the big  table in  LateX

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Well there are few packages that can help you to do that. For compose big tables you can use the package `longtable` and create tables through more than one page. You can also use `tabularx` for control better the width of the columns, the package `rotating` for rotate very wide tables (as the one in yor example) and `booktabs` for get a more professional layout easily. Take a look at [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) you can understand better how to work with tables.

Comment: It looks like `longtable` could be useful. Given the size of it, I'd be tempted to store the entries in a `.csv` file and then read them in using `pgfplotstable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ltxtable latexpackage

This package is a wrapper around tabularx (that allows you to not specify the length of a column - for you the 4th one -) and longtable

By default the first line is repeated under all pages.

the main problem with this package is that the table needs to be written in another file. But you can do that like this:

```
\newcommand{\oldinput}[1]{\input{#1}}
\renewcommand{\input}[1]{#1}
\LTXtable{\linewidth}{%
  \begin{longtable}{cccXc}
  \end{longtable}
}
\renewcommand{\input}[1]{\oldinput{#1}}
```

If this pice of code is a little long you can set it into a command or environment (with the `\newEnviron` command provided by environ package) or `\newenvironment` and replace the LTXtable bracked with `\bgroup` and `\egroup`

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|r|l|c|X|l|}\hline
ID & Authors & Year & Title & Venue     \\\hline

... the tabular lines

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```